# Is it possible to pass a dictionary in a wrapper in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, python-3.7, args

I have a function that takes some arguments and uses some variables (but not all) in my dictionary:

```py
def my_fun(arg1, arg2, arg3, **my_dict):
    does something...

    return output
```

I need to create a wrapper for this function that only takes 1 argument because I am using the multiprocessing pool package (which only allows 1 argument):

```py
def wrapper(arg):
    output = my_fun(arg)
```

Is it possible to pass `arg1, arg2, arg3, **my_dict` through the wrapper somehow using `arg`?

When I try:

```py
def wrapper(**arg):
    output = my_fun(arg)
```

I get the error `TypeError: wrapper() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.` Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain why you think only one argument can be used?

Comment: Can you also share how you are using/calling the multiprocessing pool?

Comment: avoid using `dict` as a variable name too.

Comment: Is that method inside a class? The "takes x positional args but x+1 were given" can happen if you forget to add "self".

Comment: @KlausD. I am using a pre-written (not by me) optimizer code that calls the multiprocess pool as `pool.map(problem_function, x)`. Based on what I've been trying, it seems that `problem_function` in `pool.map` can only take 1 argument. Please correct me if I'm missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic = {"a":1,"b":2}

def my_fun(arg1, arg2, arg3, **dic):
    output = arg1, arg2, arg3, dic
    return output

def wrapper(arg):
    return my_fun(arg[0],arg[1], arg[2], **dic)


x = wrapper([1,2,3, dic])
print(x)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

Comment: I will try this! On a related note, what is the difference between `x = wrapper([1,2,3, dic])` and `x = wrapper([1,2,3, **dic])`. Is the latter just incorrect?

Comment: the **Kwargs is used to pass many keyworded argument list. Using a list as argument [1,2,3,dic] you pass one argument that is a list and you cannot use the **dic in a list, you just pass the dic as an object of the list and then you can use the dic as argument of the wrapper function when you return my_func(arg[0] .... **dic). If you want to know more about https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `**dict` in your wrapper because `**` is part of the function signature syntax, and doesn't have a meaning elsewhere.

You want `my_fun` to accept 3 mandatory positional arguments followed by zero or more keyword arguments and you want these in a wrapper that you can pass as a single argument. One way to do this is to pass a dict to your function

```
kwargs=dict(arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3, arg4="four", arg5="five")
output = my_fun(**kwargs)
```

Then inside `my_fun` do your own validation for the presence of the required arguments `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`.

Though I agree with Klaus D. that you may be trying to solve a non-problem here.